# Dense $G_{\delta}$ set with $\sigma$-porous complement is cofinite?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and $D\subseteq X$ be a

- proper, connected, and dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X$,
- $X-D$ is $\sigma$-porous.

*Then is $X-D$ contained in a finite-dimensional subspace $E$ of $X$?*

**This seems at least plausible since Corollary [3.4 of this paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s2-38.1.125) shows that the codimension of a prous set in (finite-dimensions) is less than the entire space... **

**Background/Definition(s)**

- *σ-porous:*  A set $A$ is $\sigma$-porous if it can be covered by a *countable* number of porous sets.
- *porous:* A set $A$ is [porous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porous_set) if for each $a \in A$, every $\lambda\in (0,1)$, and every $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $b \in X-A$ satisfying
  $$
  d(a,b)< ε \mbox{ and } B(b,\lambda d(a,b)) \cap A=\emptyset.
  $$
- Facts: I can be shown that if $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ then any porous set is of Lebesgue measure $0$, Haar-null, and nowhere dense.  However, it can be shown that (even in this finite-dimensional setting) there exist sets which are either Lebesgue measure $0$, Haar-null, or nowhere dense but fail to be $\sigma$-porous.

Comment: For those of us who do not have access to the paper, could you recall the definition of ($\sigma$-)porous?

Comment: There are easy infinitely countable discrete subsets $\ A\subseteq\ell^2\ $ which are not contained in any finite-dimensional linear subspace. Of course, each such $\ A\ $ is $\sigma$-porous, while $\ D:=\ell^2\setminus A\ $ is a dense connected $G_\delta$- set. This would be a counter-example. (I'll propose a modification of the OP's conjecture below). Possibly, I have missed something the big way.

Comment: **A modified conjecture:** .... ...... Then $\ D\ $ contains an infinite-dimensional linear subspace.

Comment: My comments were a knee-jerk reaction meaning that I didn't take time to see the actual answer written by @Wojowu six hours earlier, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it, the feedback was still very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\ell_\infty$ and let $D$ be the complement of the set $\{(x_n)\in\ell_\infty:x_n\neq 0\text{ for at most one $n$}\}$. This last set is clearly closed, so $D$ is open, in particular $G_\delta$. It is further clearly a proper, connected, dense subset. Let us now show that $X-D$ is porous, hence $\sigma$-porous.

Let us take $\alpha=1/4$ and arbitrary $x\in X,r>0$. The ball $B(x,r/2)$ necessarily contains a point $y$ all of whose coordinates have absolute value at least $r/4$. Now the ball $B(y,r/4)$ is contained in $B(x,r)$ and is clearly disjoint from $X-D$. Thus we conclude $X-D$ is porous.

Finally, $X-D$ is not contained in a subspace of finite dimension, since $(1,0,0,\dots),(0,1,0,\dots),(0,0,1,\dots)$ is an infinite linearly independent subset of $X-D$.

In fact, let me note that almost the exact same construction shows that your claim regarding Corollary 3.4 of the paper is *incorrect*, at least when understood in terms of the dimension of the subspace spanned. The only claims the paper makes are about the Hausdorff dimension of that set.

Comment: This is a very interesting/simple/illustrative counter-example.   Thank you.

Comment: I always thought that $\ell_\infty$ wasn't separable...